# Register instance with mef2 in uwp

Tags: dependency-injection, win-universal-app, mef, mef2

I downloaded the nuget package Microsoft.Composition and tried to register a service with mef2. It seems the whole framework changed. CompositionContainer, AggregateCatalog and the RegistrationBuilder are gone. The CompositionContainer seems to be replaced by the CompositeHost. I tried to register my instance on the CompositeHost but there are only functions for GetExport.

How can I register my instance to the CompositeHost?

Also I couldn't find a documentation how to use mef2 in uwp.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Does not seem there is a way to inject an existing instance into the container.

Comment: It seems that System.Composition was moved into CoreFX https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=System.Composition Maybe we should ask there by an issue for further information?